# Naive Bayes Classifier and training data

Tags: python, naivebayes

I'm using the Naive Bayes Classifier from nltk to perform sentiment analysis on some tweets. I'm training the data using the corpus file found here: https://towardsdatascience.com/creating-the-twitter-sentiment-analysis-program-in-python-with-naive-bayes-classification-672e5589a7ed, as well as using the method there.

When creating the training set I've done it using all ~4000 tweets in the data set but I also thought I'd test with a very small amount of 30.

When testing with the entire set, it only returns 'neutral' as the labels when using the classifier on a new set of tweets but when using 30 it will only return positive, does this mean my training data is incomplete or too heavily 'weighted' with neutral entries and is the reason for my classifier only returning neutral when using ~4000 tweets in my training set?

I've included my full code below.

```py
twitter_api = twitter.Api(consumer_key = consumer_key,
                         consumer_secret = consumer_secret,
                         access_token_key = access_token,
                         access_token_secret = access_token_secret)
# Test set builder

def buildtestset(keyword):
    try: 
        min_id = None
        tweets = []
        ids = []
        for i in range(0,50):
            tweetsdata = twitter_api.GetSearch(keyword, count = 100, max_id = min_id )
            for t in tweetsdata:
                tweets.append(t)
                ids.append(t.id)  
            min_id = min(ids)

        print(str(len(tweets))+ ' tweets found for keyword: '+keyword)
        return[{"text":status.text, "label":None} for status in tweets]

    except:
        print('this is so sad')
        return None
# Quick test

keyword = 'bicycle'

testdataset = buildtestset(keyword)

# Training set builder

def buildtrainingset(corpusfile,tweetdata): 
    #corpusfile = pathway to corpus data
    #tweetdata = pathway to file we going to save all the tweets to
    corpus = []

    with open(corpusfile,'r') as csvfile:
        linereader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',', quotechar = "\"")
        for row in linereader:
            corpus.append({'tweet_id':row[2],'label':row[1],'topic':row[0]})

    # Append every tweet from corpusfile to our corpus list

    rate_limit = 180
    sleep_time = 900/180
    # these are set up so we call enough times to be within twitters guidelines

    # the rest is calling the api of every tweet to get the status object, text associated with it and then put it in our
    # data set - trainingdata
    trainingdata = []
    count = 0
    for tweet in corpus:
        if count < 30:
            try:
                status = twitter_api.GetStatus(tweet['tweet_id'])
                print ('Tweet fetched '+status.text)
                tweet['text'] = status.text
                trainingdata.append(tweet)
                time.sleep(sleep_time)
                count += 1
            except:
                count += 1
                continue
        #write tweets to empty csv

    with open(tweetdata,'w',encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        linewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',quotechar = "\"")
        for tweet in trainingdata:
            try: 
                linewriter.writerow([tweet['tweet_id'],tweet['text'],tweet['label'],tweet['topic']])

            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
    return trainingdata

corpusfile = (r'C:\Users\zacda\OneDrive\Desktop\DATA2901\Assignment\corpusmaster.csv')
tweetdata = (r'C:\Users\zacda\OneDrive\Desktop\DATA2901\Assignment\tweetdata.csv')

TrainingData = buildtrainingset(corpusfile,tweetdata)

import re # regular expression library 
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from string import punctuation 
from nltk.corpus import stopwords 

class preprocesstweets:
    def __init__(self):
        self._stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english') + list(punctuation) + ['AT_USER','URL'])

    def processtweets(self, list_of_tweets):
        processedtweets=[]
        for tweet in list_of_tweets:  
            processedtweets.append((self._processtweet(tweet["text"]),tweet["label"]))
        return processedtweets

    def _processtweet(self, tweet):
        tweet = tweet.lower() # convert text to lower-case
        tweet = re.sub('((www\.[^\s]+)|(https?://[^\s]+))', 'URL', tweet) # remove URLs
        tweet = re.sub('@[^\s]+', 'AT_USER', tweet) # remove usernames
        tweet = re.sub(r'#([^\s]+)', r'\1', tweet) # remove the # in #hashtag
        tweet = word_tokenize(tweet) # remove repeated characters (helloooooooo into hello)
        return [word for word in tweet if word not in self._stopwords]

tweetprocessor = preprocesstweets()
processedtrainingdata = tweetprocessor.processtweets(TrainingData)
processedtestdata = tweetprocessor.processtweets(testdataset)

# This is a list of all the words we have in the training set, the word_features is a list of all the distinct words w freq
import nltk

def buildvocab(processedtrainingdata):
    all_words = []

    for (words, sentiment) in processedtrainingdata:
        all_words.extend(words)

    wordlist = nltk.FreqDist(all_words)
    word_features = wordlist.keys()

    return word_features

def extract_features(tweet):
    tweet_words = set(tweet)
    features = {}
    for word in word_features:
        features['contains(%s)' % word] = (word in tweet_words) #creates json key containing word x, its loc.
        # Every key has a T/F according - true for present , false for not
    return features 
# Building the feature vector

word_features = buildvocab(processedtrainingdata)
training_features = nltk.classify.apply_features(extract_features, processedtrainingdata)
# apply features does the actual extraction
# Naive Bayes Classifier 
Nbayes = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_features)

Nbayes_result_labels = [Nbayes.classify(extract_features(tweet[0])) for tweet in processedtestdata]

# get the majority vote [?]
if Nbayes_result_labels.count('positive') > Nbayes_result_labels.count('negative'):
    print('Positive')
    print(str(100*Nbayes_result_labels.count('positive')/len(Nbayes_result_labels)))
elif Nbayes_result_labels.count('negative') > Nbayes_result_labels.count('positive'):
    print(str(100*Nbayes_result_labels.count('negative')/len(Nbayes_result_labels)))
    print('Negative sentiment')
else:
    print('Neutral')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing machine learning, we want to learn an algorithms that performs well on new (unseen) data. This is called generalization.

The purpose of the test set is, amongst others, to verify the generalization behavior of your classifier. If your model predicts the same labels for each test instance, than we cannot confirm that hypothesis. The test set should be representative of the conditions in which you apply it later.

As a rule of thumb, I like to think that you keep 50-25% of their data as a test set. This of course depends on the situation. 30/4000 is less than one percent.

A second point that comes to mind is that when your classifier is biased towards one class, make sure each class is represented nearly equally in the training and validation set. This prevents the classifier from 'just' learning the distribution of the whole set, instead of learning which features are relevant.

As a final note, normally we report metrics such as precision, recall and F<sub>β=1</sub> to evaluate our classifier. The code in your sample seems to report something based on the global sentiment in all tweets, are you sure that is what you want? Are the tweets a representative collection?